# save nested adapter states (FragmentPagerAdapter + ListViewAdapter)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-configchanges

My Activity has a simple viewPager + viewPagerAdapter:

```
public class SearchFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // holds fragments placed in the viewPager
    private SparseArray<SearchFragment> mFragments;

    public SearchFragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, String queryText) {
        super(fragmentManager);

        mFragments = new SparseArray<SearchFragment>();
        List<Fragment> savedFragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();

        // try to restore fragments from fragmentManager
        if (savedFragments != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < savedFragments.size(); i++) {
                if (savedFragments.get(i) instanceof SearchFragment) {
                    mFragments.put(i, (SearchFragment) savedFragments.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        SearchFragment fragment = mFragments.get(position);
        return (fragment == null) ? new SearchFragment() : fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        // see if we already have this fragment
        SearchFragment fragment = mFragments.get(position);

        // if not => instantiate new fragment
        if (fragment == null) {
            final SearchFragment searchFragment = (SearchFragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            mFragments.put(position, searchFragment);
            return searchFragment;
        }

        return fragment;
    }         
}
```

In every page of the viewPager is one SearchFragment. Every SearchFragment has only a ListView + listViewAdapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Suggestion> {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // typical holder pattern
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.row_suggestion, parent, false);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Every row of the listView has a button that start another Activity (YouTubePlayer, but that's not important). 
After the YouTube video is finished or the user clicks the back button, the YouTubePlayer-Activity closes and my own Activity + ViewPager + SearchFragments in ViewPages + ListViews in SearchFragments are shown again.

Although I can restore
- the position of the viewPager (I save it in a field of the Activity)
- the SearchFragments in the viewPager (see the constructor of SearchFragmentAdapter above)

I cannot restore the ListView and the ListViewAdapter which hold the content and the scrolling position of any of the ListViews. 
Of course, the same happens on configuration changes: The Activity is built again and can restore the position of the viewPager from its field, but the scrolling position and especially the content of the SearchFragments are lost.

**How can I restore at least the content of the listViews (the scrolling position is just a nice-to-have) after the device was rotated?**

I read a lot about state saving of viewPagers and ListViews, but there is hardly good information about state saving with this combination (viewPager + listView = 2 adapters with their own states and content).